# kinetic how to setDraggable(false)

Tags: kineticjs

Basically dipping my toe into kinetic JS and trying to create a simple drawing application for allowing the user to create very basic electronic circuit diagrams. The user can select for example a resistor and click on the stage/canvas to place it. My code simply draws the lines for resistor symbol in a group and places them, In addition to the lines of the electronic symbol, in the group, I've a red dot at each end which should allow interconnection of the electronic component.

Now sometimes I want to allow the user to "drag" interconnections/lines between the symbols and sometimes to move entire symbol so the user selects a mode of operation. If the user selects "move" mode then on a mousedown the group sets "draggable" to true. This works fine but when the user releases the mouse I wanted to set "draggable" back to false so that the user can select other possible actions. I'm finding that if I set "draggable" to "true" I can't set draggable back to false. Once I set the "move" mode, and move the group, then that group is forever moveable regardless of the current mode of operation. So when I select the interconnect mode the group's draggable status over rules the interconnection.

The API documents state that setDraggable() accepts a string parameter. I've tried "" and "false" but neither stop the group from being draggable.

Is there another way to do this or is the setDraggable sort of a one way method?

Comment: Sorted! I was setting draggable false in a "mouseup" handler which seems to be ignored. Moved it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the newest 4.0.1 release.
See this [forum posting](http://www.kineticjs.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=994&p=3175#p3175) & [git-hub change log](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log)

But if you are using 3.10.5 or slightly older, it should be working fine. Try posting part of your code that can be looked upon

Answer (score 0):

Try this.setDraggable("false");

Comment: Could you be more specific?